# Modifying request contents in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, httprequest

As far as I know request objects are immutable and it's bad practice to modify request through closed attributes like request._body or request._data. And since it described everywhere as bad practice, I'm lack of details to understand why it's should be avoided. What is the best approach to dynamically change request (for example if we need to decode value in request.body).

As I alternative I can imagine custom Serializer with custom decode serializer.Field but maybe there's more clever solution? Thank you in advance!

Comment: why do you want to modify the request contents ??

Comment: Hi, I need to decode incomming data. Want to create dynamic solution so I could ideally use mixin-like solution in view and pass "fields to decode" to some view like decode_fields = ['field1'] (for ex.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to modify the request content in DRF is to create a custom parser. You can subclass one of the existing parsers and override the parse method to apply your decoding or other changes.  You can then use the @parser_classes decorator to apply the custom parser to specific views.